# youtube API: Get mosts popular video uploaded by a user

Tags: api, youtube

Here is the original URL to get the xml awnser:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/RIPPERvideos/uploads

I would like to get all the videos uploaded by this specific user (not be limitted to 20). Also I would like the data to be sorted.

I tried these params:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/RIPPERvideos/uploads?orderby?v=viewCount

It only seems to be working for these kind of request:
gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?
    q=football+-soccer
    &orderby=published
    &start-index=11
    &max-results=10
    &v=2

Can someone help or guide me?

thanks

Comment: Can someone help me please! I really need a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

The URL structure isn't correct, try this (which works):

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/RIPPERvideos/uploads?orderby=viewCount
```